# Tensorflow Serving Type: Object is not of expected type: uint8

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

So I'm trying to serve COCO via tensorflow serving, if I inspect the model I get the following:

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_UINT8
        shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3)
        name: image_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 100, 4)
        name: detection_boxes:0
    outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 100)
        name: detection_classes:0
    outputs['detection_masks'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, -1, -1)
        name: detection_masks:0
    outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 100)
        name: detection_scores:0
    outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1)
        name: num_detections:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

My test code is as follows:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64
import requests
import base64
import json

image = "./frames/IMG_0474.MOV/IMG_0474_100.jpg"
URL = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/saved_model/versions/1:predict" 
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
image_content = base64.b64encode(cv2.imread(image)).decode("utf-8")
body = {
    "signature_name": "serving_default",
    "inputs": [{"image": {"b64":image_content}}]
    }
r = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(body), headers = headers) 
print(r.text)
```

Which yields:

```
"error": "JSON Value: {\n    \"b64\": [massive long base64 string]}\n} Type: Object is not of expected type: uint8" }
```

Also tried(same result):

```
body = {
    "signature_name": "serving_default",
    "instances": [{"inputs": {"b64":image_content}}]
    }
```

And finally(Same result):

```
body = {
    "signature_name": "serving_default",
    "inputs": {"b64":image_content}
    }
```

I also double checked before the file is base64 encoded by doing:

```
print(image.dtype)
```

Output is uint8!

I've also tried tinkering with the object, ie remove image and just having the array with "b64" "..." - no joy.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try loading the image in opencv and convert it to a list and send that. You don't have to encode it in base64 format. It should work then.

```
import json
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64
import requests
import base64
import json

image = "./frames/IMG_0474.MOV/IMG_0474_100.jpg"
URL = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/saved_model/versions/1:predict" 
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
image_content = cv2.imread(image,1).astype('uint8').tolist()
body = {"instances": [{"inputs": image_content}]}
r = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(body), headers = headers) 
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Heya thanks I think i tried this, i'll test it now. If that works it's going to be a serious facepalm moment lol

Comment: { "error": "slice index 2 of dimension 0 out of bounds.\n\t [[{{node Preprocessor/map/while/ResizeToRange/strided_slice_2}}]]" } is the response I get now, lemmy google it!

Comment: Hey mate no, still that error I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: So all this is based on the MASK RCNN implemetnation from matterport

Comment: I really need this soon so if you've implemented this before have a look here, grab their COCO model https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN and I'll up the bounty to 300 if you can make it serve the standard coco model? We're rushing at a launch date for https://www.tothehighstreet.com and I'm very overloaded! Also if you DO make it work it'd be worth looking up marcfielding on LinkedIn as there may even be some day rate work for you(I'm the AWS guy with tortoise on my photo)

Comment: Hey mate, it's done. Have sent a request on LinkedIn!

Comment: Yo so I've replied to your message if we can answer this question I'll up the bounty we'll continue our conversation to move forward on linkedIn!

Comment: Actually though I dunno how I increase a bounty let me look! If I can't edit it, and if your answer works I'll award that now and award another 200 after(assuming that works)

Comment: I've implemented COCO model from TensorFlow hub as they will release new updates when they retrain, so it's better to use that in the long run, it has the same signature so shouldn't be a problem. 
If you still want to go with matterport implementation, assuming you have setup everything. 

Change the json body to this -
body = {"instances": [{"inputs":cv2.imread(image,1).astype('uint8').tolist()}] }

It should work.

Comment: I just looked at the model link, it's the same one. So it should work. let me know anyhow.